# Can Float32 ever be not equal float in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, floating-point

The ObjC's library functions seem to be using `Float32` and `float` interchangeably. For example the Accelerate framework declares function arguments as `float` (and `double`) where as you can see `Float32` used in AudioUnit declarations.

If you are dealing with audio, a lot of values end up being kicked around between these frameworks. The question for me is (as someone who usually prefers keywords over typedef's, e.g. `float` over `Float32`) - which data type to use in my own declarations? Can for example `Float32` ever be not the same as `float`?

Comment: "Ever" is a long time. So who knows, it might become a different size, one day in the future. Currently, they are the same. But seriously: since the language does not seem to require that a float is 32 bit, if you really need a type that is certain to use 32 bits, you should probably use `Float32`. If you only need something that does not take up too much memory but still can handle floating point, use `float`. In other words, in this context, use `float` for a generic rather simple floating point type while you use `Float32` for a fixed size floating point type.

Comment: For audio, which requires a fixed size type to be stored in its files, I would use Float32. For general calculations, I would use float or double.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis what I need is one thing, but what frameworks and libraries require us to do is another ;) Like I said, the Accelerate framework uses `float`, where as in a lot of other places, including related to media, you can see `Float32` and `Float64`. This poses a question what to use in the code that uses these libraries. If `float` changes its size some day, it may have consequences for your code either way, whether you used it directly or the typedefs.

Comment: Use what the libraries require. Audio etc. use Float32 and Float64 because it stores many of these values in files so the exact size is important, for portability reasons. If the values are not stored, the exact size is less important. But, if possible, do not mix 32 bit and 64 bit floats any more than absolutely necessary.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis again, Accelerate, which may be used for audio processing, declares its prototypes with `float` and `double` arguments. And no, audio is rarely stored as floating point, but more often it's integer. CoreAudio can convert it to float for you for easy manipulation, including the Accelerate framework!

Comment: OK, I got now that Accelerate also does DSP etc. I would use what the libraries use. If a type is declared as Float32, then use that. If it is declared as float, then use that.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, DSP, but I don't think you understand the question, and we are going in circles. Please re-read everything before commenting.

Comment: I did read everything. My reply remains the same: what you use depends on for what you use it.